# TextureLoader.load() returned texture has undefined image on IE11

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using `Three.js`, I have made a `3D globe` for a website.

To load texture on that globe, I am using the following code:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

loader.load(imageString, function (texture) {

    var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry( RADIUS, SEGMENTS, RINGS );

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
        map: texture,
        overdraw: 0.5
    });

    globeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, material);

    globe.add(globeMesh);

});
```

Where `"imageString"` is a string that points to an image on the server.

This works fine for most browsers, and the globe shows up great! However, on IE11 I cannot see the globe as it has no Mesh. Using the debugger, I can see that the `texture` that is returned on `load()` has the `image` property of `undefined`, whereas in other browsers that contain the string previously-stored in `"imageString"`.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is here? Is this a known issue with IE11? I have included the Promise polyfill just in case that was the problem, but that didn't help.

Comment: Does the following official example work on IE11 https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_cube? You should see a textured box.

Comment: No - I just see a black screen. I guess that means that IE11 doesn't support a technique used in `TextureLoader`.

Comment: `TextureLoader` internally uses `ImageLoader`. And `ImageLoader` just uses plain HTML image objects for texture loading. So absolutely basic stuff. Can you also test with a different windows device?

Comment: @Mugen87 I just tested that example on IE 11, and it's not showing for me either. Upon closer inspection, it looks like IE 11 [is not requesting the `crate.gif` image](https://imgur.com/a/nFUVhp5) like any other browser would. I then tested my local copy of the same example [and it *does* get requested](https://imgur.com/a/aEKwRSH). So weird... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @NathanAkrill Probably best to report this to Microsoft.

Comment: @Mugen87 I think I found it. Looks like IE [doesn't support `<script type="module">`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module). My local copy was using the old way of importing the library.

Comment: You're totally right! Now I remember that we officially stopped IE11 support for the examples^^. Oops, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance using `<script type="module">` on your code? If so, [IE 11 does not have support for it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module). After testing the `geometry_cube` example mentioned by Mugen87 above, I noticed that IE doesn't work with the following method to import Three.js:

```
<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
    var camera, scene, renderer;
```

Here's the resulting screenshot:

[image]

---

### Solution:

In order to import `Three.js` to work with IE, you'll have to use the older method:

```
<script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    // ...
```

[image]

This older method works! In fact, now that Three.js is slowly migrating to the module method, you'll find that the entire [threejs examples section](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_cloth) won't run on IE 11:

[image]

Comment: I am not using any `<script type="module">` tags in my code at all, so unfortunately that's not the problem

Comment: I've got the same problem. And this is also not the solution for me.